# Check for IsPostBack in external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

From an extrnal Javascript file, I need to check for `IsPostBack` (ASP.NET page). Here is what I found after googling:

```
var isPostBack = <%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>;
```

But  `<%=`  `%>` doesn't seem to be recognized in the external JS file. If so, what is the alternate solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do that from an external file.  Even if you could, external files get cached on the client's browser, and they don't get pulled every time.  You might be able to place a function in the page and call it from the external script.

**External Script**

```
if(isAPostBack)
{
//run code
}
```

**ASPX Page** (Script in header)

```
var isAPostBack = <%= Page.IsPostBack %>;
```

Just make sure that your external script gets loaded after the above line in the page.

Answer (score 3):

For ASP code to be processed you need to have a file extension which is mapped to the ASP dll in IIS.

The simplest case here would be to rename your `.js` file with a `.aspx` extension, then change the src attribute of your `<script>` element.

Alternatively, create your `isPostBack` variable globally in your `aspx` page, and then call your `js` file which contains its usage, eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isPostBack = <%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js"></script> <!-- <- script that uses isPostBack -->
```

Comment: Changing the extension to aspx would not work because `isPostBack` will always be `false` when the page (script) is loaded from a script tag - even when the parent page has `isPostBack == true`. -1 for that, but +1 for your alternative solution.  Net vote = 0.

Comment: @gilly3 good point about the variable always being false in a script tag - my bad. Glad I at least broke even though :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `<%= %>` notation in an external JavaScript file; it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in a Javascript file cause the Server will serve it as such  and wont recognize the asp tags. You could do this, however, from a aspx file and it will work. You could also use a Generic Handler.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can only render this `variable` through the aspx page or user control or master page used on the page.